# MongoDB like query

Tags: regex, mongodb

Hi my collections contains following documents structure

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf7d"), "memoryUtilization" : "10",    "cpuUtilization" : "4", "hostId" : "10.9.1.3", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" :  "snmp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf7e"), "memoryUtilization" : "31", "cpuUtilization" : "0", "hostId" : "10.9.1.14", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" : "snmp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf7f"), "memoryUtilization" : "61", "cpuUtilization" : "12", "hostId" : "10.9.10.40", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" : "snmp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf80"), "memoryUtilization" : "61", "cpuUtilization" : "12", "hostId" : "10.9.17.41", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" : "snmp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf81"), "memoryUtilization" : "55", "cpuUtilization" : "10", "hostId" : "10.9.1.42", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" : "snmp" }
```

Now I want all documents whose hostId start with "10.9.1" so my result should be as below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf7d"), "memoryUtilization" : "10",    "cpuUtilization" : "4", "hostId" : "10.9.1.3", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" :  "snmp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf7e"), "memoryUtilization" : "31", "cpuUtilization" : "0", "hostId" : "10.9.1.14", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" : "snmp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5242c91044aef624318eaf81"), "memoryUtilization" : "55", "cpuUtilization" : "10", "hostId" : "10.9.1.42", "timestamp" : 1379570550000, "device_type" : "snmp" }
```

for that I was write following query but it not work

```
db.collectionsname.find({"hostId":/10.9.1./})
```

it shows me all results whose contains hostId like 10.9.1.42,10.9.10.40 etc So any one knows how should I will write query?

Comment: `.` is a special character in regex, you need to escape it

Comment: @Sammaye I think you should post it as answer

Comment: @Sammaye Hi I changed my query as below it work fine  db.collectionsname.find({"hostId":/10.9.1\./})

Comment: Hi any knows how to write same query in java using java mongo api

Answer (score 1):

Use `db.collectionsname.find({"hostId":/^10\.9\.1\./})`. *(Edited after comment)*

`.` is a special character in regex, which match every character, usually with exception of newlines (but here comes some language-dependent differences).

Comment: It should be `/^10\.9\.1\./`.